# How to find function names in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

How do I find all function names in unity using Microsoft visual studio code when there are so many I only know one function name applydamage. I know the template for creating unity script it's the functions and completions that are difficult.

I asked the unity forum community but didn't understand what they were saying and I try to google to see if I can find encyclopedia for unity function and completion names